# XML Serialization and List<enum> c#

Tags: c#, xml, list, serialization, enums

I am trying to serialise a `List<>` of enums with the `XMLSerializer` when I get the following **Error**:

```
'GameDataBuilder.vshost.exe' (Managed): Loaded 'uoqssn9i'
A first chance exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in uoqssn9i
A first chance exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException' occurred in uoqssn9i
A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Xml.dll
An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Xml.dll
```

I have taken a look inside the `List<>` and all of the values are valid. Using the same code I can serialize an enum (not list) and all other types (int, float etc) and Lists of those other types just fine. It just seems like the list of enum causes errors.

Anyone came across this problem before?

Any help would be much appreciated

**edit**:

Serialize Method:

```
public void SerialiseToXML(XmlSerializer serializer, string directory)
{

    string fileName = directory + m_Name + ".xml";

    if (!Directory.Exists(directory))
    {
        DirectoryInfo di = Directory.CreateDirectory(directory);
    }

    if (!File.Exists(fileName))
    {
        using(File.Create(fileName))
        {
        }
    }

    using (TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter(fileName))
    {
        serializer.Serialize(textWriter, m_Objects);
    }
}
```

Serializer:

```
private void GenerateSerializer()
{
    List<Type> dynamiclyCreatedTypes = mTypeManager.GetSerializeableTypes();
    m_Serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<ISerializeable>), dynamiclyCreatedTypes.ToArray());
}
```

The List Is Generated like this:

```
type = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(type);
```

Comment: can you post the snippet that you are using to serialize ?

Comment: Actually, how do you create the XmlSerializer that you pass in.

Comment: The Enum in question is generated using reflection at runtime, although it serializes fine when it is not in a list

Comment: The ISerializable interface has *nothing* to do with XML serialization, so it doesn't make sense to serialize a list of ISerializable objects...

Comment: Please add the "GenerateSerializer" method to your question.

Comment: ISerializeable is just a blank class that I have made, probably bad naming but it is just an empty parentclass

Comment: `ISerializeable` is a very bad name for a class because the `I` prefix is used for interfaces, not classes, and the name is a predefined BCL interface. Change your class name.

Comment: Class name in this case has nothing to do with what is going wrong

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are using `typeof(List<ISerializeable>)` to create the XmlSerializer. Serializers cannot work of interfaces, you need to provide them with a concrete type.

Can you use this `typeof(List<EnumType>)` instead ?

Comment: The enum is in the extra types (dynamicallyCreatedTypes), The Serializer is also serializing a lot of other types too, so typeof(List<EnumType>) wouldn't be ideal but I will try it to see

Comment: Just to clarify, the list of enums (and all other types to output) are within a class which is a child of ISerializeable